# How to automatically refresh JMX attributes in jconsole

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx

For monitoring my application, I set up the Mbean. To automatically update the status variable, I started a thread from the constructor of the montiored bean. The status is being updated. I am able to view the status through jconsole and by refreshing updated value is being shown. But i want to get the updated value automatically in jconsole.

```
public interface StatusManagerMBean {

    public long getStatus();
}


public class StatusManager implements StatusManagerMBean {

   private long status;

   public long getStatus() {
      return this.status;
    }

  public StatusManager(int numThreads) { 

        new Thread() { 
                      public void run() {
                while (true) {
                            //update status
                               try {
                                  sleep(10 * 1000);
                                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                 }
                           }
                    } 
                }.start();

   }


}
```

Comment: Implement your own JConsole...

Answer (score 0):

The Memory tab of jConsole has an automatically refreshing graph.

The [JTop](http://jtop.sourceforge.net/) Plugin has autorefresh.

Or have a look at the [hibernate-jconsole](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate-jcons/)  plugin.